# How can I wait for the result of rxjs/fromEvent() in an Angular 10 app

Tags: angular, rxjs

Currently, I'm developing a document parser based on the DOM in Angular 10. In the first step I need to load all images because their dimensions are required.

```
createDoc(header: ElementRef, footer: ElementRef, content: ElementRef): Observable<any> {

    const docParts = () => from([header, footer, content]);

    const request = (url: string) =>
        this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).pipe(
            map(response => {
                let img = new Image();
                img.src = url;

                return fromEvent(img, 'load').pipe(
                    map(event => {
                        let loadedImage: any = event.currentTarget;

                        return {
                            buffer: response,
                            width: loadedImage.width,
                            height: loadedImage.height,
                        };
                    })
                );
            }),
            tap(response => {
                console.log('--- Image:', url, response);

                this.imageList[url] = response;
            })
        );


    return from([header, footer, content]).pipe(
        delay(100),

        switchMap(response => forkJoin(this.getImages(response).map(url => request(url)))),

        switchMap(docParts),

        concatMap((elem: any) => {
            return of(this.generateDocx(elem));
        }),

        toArray(),

        map(response => {
            ...
            return response;
        })
    );
}

generateDocx(node:ElementRef): string[] {
    ...
    // apply values from "imageList"
    ...
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that `fromEvent` returns an observable and I can't find a way to access the value. But this value is required in `generateDocx()`. So, how can I load the images to get their dimensions and process only after images are loaded?

Comment: `generateDocx` needs to subscribe to `createDoc`. Can you also share the code of `generateDocx`?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner pls can you describe what you mean. I'm not sure how do you mean this

Comment: You said, `generateDocx` needs to access the value within `from`. Can you edit your question and add  `generateDocx` function as well?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I edited the example. The `generateDocx` is a native functions that gets en `ElementRef` and returns a native datatype (string for example)

Comment: I'm afraid what you want is not possible. Since `createDoc` is an async function and its callers have to work that way too. `generateDocx` has to return an `Observable` or `Promise`

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner ok, I understand. I tried to modify my internal code so that `generateDocx` will return an Observable. But even then it wont work. Maybe the `fromEvent` is a wrong approach?

Comment: It will work. It is just at some point in your call stack, someone has to subscribe to the observable. It does not matter whether `fromEvent` returns it or some other function. `Observable`s are lazy by default, they won't execute (in your case, won't make an http call) unless someone subscribe to them. `createDoc` returns an `Observable`, `generateDocx` can apply its own logic with rxjs operators and return it and so on. Just make sure, someone will subscribe to it at the end.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I'm sure that it will work in this simplified example. The subscribe is done on `createDoc`. But because `fromEvent` returns an Observable too, I had to do a subscribe on `generateDocx` as you have suggested. But this is not possible with my current code. But thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain what you could do based on our conversation in the comment section.

I assume you have component which creates a document upon user's request. Let's call it `DocCreateComponent` and it has a `createDocument(someData)` method. This component calls some `function`/`service` which eventually calls `generateDocx` and `createDoc` as you mentioned in your question. To visualize our call stack it would look like following

```js
http.get (@createDoc)
createDoc (@generateDocx)
generateDocx (@someFunc)
.
.
.
createDocument (@DocCreateComponent)
```

I'd make `createDocument` within `DocCreateComponent` subscribe to outer most `Observable` and everyone else between would **NEVER** subscribe. They would just use `operators` to manipulate/add some logic on the data. If you subscribe to an `Observable`, you get `Subscription` object which is not useful to anyone else. Keep in mind, your middle guys (`services`/`functions`) should return `Observable` (for most of the time, there could be some exceptions).